# Adding Scripts to ScriptManager on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a tricky scenario whereby I want to add ScriptManager scriptreference only on some conditions as follows

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="scriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
<CompositeScript>
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference path=/...." />
    </Scripts>
</CompositeScript>
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

I want to make this script reference only on specific condition, so I did as below

```
<% if(xyzclass.property)
{ %>

above code

<% } %>
```

Once I do that, I get the error as

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

I googled up and tried to add '#' as <%# but by adding '#' it can't find the class (xyzclass) and so get the error as

```
Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
```

I tried doing the work as mentioned here too
http://leedumond.com/blog/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks/

No luck so far. If I take the approach as mentioned in above link, it says something like

```
The base class includes the field '', but its type (System.Web.UI.ScriptManagerProxy) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager).
```

Guys, what I need is just to add scripts via ScriptManager ONLY dynamically. Is there any way which is in practice good one too.

Thanks in advance,

Nimesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to add scripts based on conditions, programmably add them:

```
ScriptManager mgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
if (condition)
   mgr.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference { Path = "~/script.js" });
```

in code behind.  Or, use a ScriptManagerProxy and define them in the user control or page itself.  This is a great way to add scripts, but if you use a composite script, it does append these to the same composite script as the ScriptManager.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Mate, Already did that but doesn't work too. When I did ScriptManger1.CompositeScript.Scripts.Add(item), doesn't work. Script is not loaded in the webpage. Used Firebug to see if the scripts are there in ScriptReference.

Comment: Adding to particular ScriptManagerProxy control on the page worked for me.